# Export records to cloudkit

Tags: cloudkit

I need to export data from a dictionary of 12 thousand items to Cloudkit. I tried to use the convenience API but I keep hitting the rate limit while trying to save to the public database. I then tried the Operation API and I got a similar error. My question is: how to save a very large amount of data to cloudkit without hitting the limits?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for the `CKErrorLimitExceeded` error code, you should

> Try refactoring your request into multiple smaller batches.

So if your `CKModifyRecordsOperation` operation results in the `CKErrorLimitExceeded` error, you can just create two `CKModifyRecordsOperation` objects, each with half the data from the failed operation. If you do that recursively (so any of the split operations could also fail with the limit exceeded error, splitting again in two) then you should eventually get a number of `CKModifyRecordsOperation` objects that have a small enough number of records to avoid the error.

Comment: Do you know the small enough number?

Comment: Yes, a tardy reply; but a good question. Your best bet and the most efficient means is to use an Assets. Save all your data into a large blob of data and save that as an asset.

Comment: Its best not to use a fixed "small enough number" as it may change in subsequent iOS versions

Answer (score 0):

If you have your own server, you could try the [CloudKit Web Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloutKitWebServicesReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) API.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 10, the maximum permitted record count per operation is 400.

```
/// The system allowed maximum record modifications count.
///
/// If excute a CKModifyRecordsOperation with more than 400 record modifications, system will return a CKErrorLimitExceeded error.
private let maximumRecordModificationsLimit = 400

private func modifyRecords(recordsToSave: [CKRecord], recordIDsToDelete: [CKRecordID], previousRetryAfterSeconds: TimeInterval = 0, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

    guard !recordsToSave.isEmpty || !recordIDsToDelete.isEmpty else {
        completion?(true)
        return
    }

    func handleLimitExceeded() {
        let recordsToSaveFirstSplit = recordsToSave[0 ..< recordsToSave.count / 2]
        let recordsToSaveSecondSplit = recordsToSave[recordsToSave.count / 2 ..< recordsToSave.count]
        let recordIDsToDeleteFirstSplit = recordIDsToDelete[0 ..< recordIDsToDelete.count / 2]
        let recordIDsToDeleteSecondSplit = recordIDsToDelete[recordIDsToDelete.count / 2 ..< recordIDsToDelete.count]

        self.modifyRecords(recordsToSave: Array(recordsToSaveFirstSplit), recordIDsToDelete: Array(recordIDsToDeleteFirstSplit))
        self.modifyRecords(recordsToSave: Array(recordsToSaveSecondSplit), recordIDsToDelete: Array(recordIDsToDeleteSecondSplit), completion: completion)
    }

    if recordsToSave.count + recordIDsToDelete.count > maximumRecordModificationsLimit {
        handleLimitExceeded()
        return
    }

    // run CKModifyRecordsOperation at here
}
```